# How to generate custom PDF with text and images too

Tags: ios

I have a requirement to generate custom PDF with text and images too.The PDF should minimum 5 pages.Please can anyone help me on this.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check This   http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/generating-pdf-documents--mobile-11265   (or)  http://www.raywenderlich.com/6581/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot! but i want  to add table of contents too.When user clicks on that it has to navigate..Please can you help us

Comment: what do you want ? you want add the table data on pdf

Comment: i have to generate pdf using nsarray and i need to show table of content in the pdf.If you any sample project please share it would be a great help.Thanks Srinivas

Comment: Check This http://www.raywenderlich.com/6818/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I got from an OS X project, but it's quite much the same in iOS. I hope this leads you the right way.

```
// create PDF context to file path; these measures are for the european DIN format A4
CGRect mediaBox = CGRectMake(0, 0, 595, 842);
CGContextRef context = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)fileURL, &mediaBox,
                                                 (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)@{(NSString *)kCGPDFContextAuthor: NSFullUserName(), (NSString *)kCGPDFContextCreator: @"mubi begum's great iOS PSD generator", (NSString *)kCGPDFContextTitle: fileName});

// create paragraph style for string drawing
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle];
[paragraphStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

// create attributes for string drawing
NSMutableDictionary *drawingAttributes = [@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
                                            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [NSColor blackColor],
                                            NSFontAttributeName:            [NSFont systemFontOfSize:13]} mutableCopy];

// finally draw the string
[@"YOUR STRING" drawInRect:frameForYourString withAttributes:drawingAttributes];

// create new page
CGContextEndPage(context);
CGContextBeginPage(context, NULL);

// load image to draw
NSImage *logoImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"logo"];

// calculate image ratio and current size for drawing 
CGFloat ratio = logoImage.size.width / logoImage.size.height;

CGFloat imageHeight = 50; // or whatever fits your needs
CGFloat imageWidth = imageHeight * ratio;

// draw the image in the right top corner with 20px padding
[logoImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(mediaBox.size.width - imageWidth - 20, mediaBox.size.height - imageHeight - 20, imageWidth, imageHeight)];

// close the PDF context
CGContextEndPage(context);
CGPDFContextClose(context);
CFRelease(context);
```

**EDIT** You can also use custom fonts, CoreGraphics will properly embed the corresponding font into the PDF file.